# Why do people forget to reset their browser zoom level?

Tags: website-design, browser, zooming

I have come along this behavior quite a few times. A friend shows me something on her computer and I notice that the website looks odd because she forgot that she set the browser zoom to more than 100%.

What are the reasons people do this and why are they not noticing?

Comment: Zooming is an accessibility feature. Do you know if your friends are intentionally doing this to help them view the page?

Comment: Ask your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no clear indication to the user on the UI that the zoom level is greater or lower than 100%.

I noticed chrome is doing this indication by displaying a magnifying glass next to the bookmark star, but to be honest I just found this now doing this research. As a user, I could have had the same issue for months I would not know about it.

[image]

Maybe a solution is to have this in settings where you can turn this on until you turn it back off. And when you do it with ctrl+/- in the window the view will reset to 100% after you restart your browser.